# Change CSS using i class tag

Tags: html, css, canvas-lms

I have a situation where I am trying to update css for three different div elements that are the same except for their i class tags (they each have a different icon). I am trying to change the color of each, and I can only change css or javascript (Canvas LMS). I can change all of them, but I can not figure out the granularity and change each individually. The three are:

```
<div class="ic-notification ic-notification--admin-created ic-notification--info">
        <div class="ic-notification__icon" role="presentation">
          <i class="icon-info"></i>
          
  <div class="ic-notification ic-notification--admin-created ic-notification--info">
            <div class="ic-notification__icon" role="presentation">
              <i class="icon-calendar-month"></i>

 <div class="ic-notification ic-notification--admin-created ic-notification--info">
            <div class="ic-notification__icon" role="presentation">
              <i class="question"></i>
```

Any ideas either using css or javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: Have any parent div of **ic-notification** class element? If yes then we can use css :nth-child(n) property like **.ic-notification:nth-child(1){...}** or **.ic-notification:nth-child(2) {...}** .

Comment: The elements' positions are variable. These are announcements that are created using a rich text editor.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that depending on your overall need, here are some simple ones:

- Select the class in icon; or
- Javascript (edited)

```js
// select class
const icon = document.querySelector(".icon-info");
const calMonth = document.querySelector(".icon-calendar-month");
const question = document.querySelector(".question");

// Apply logic if need
// set color
icon.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  icon.style.color = "blue";
})
calMonth.style.color = "red";
question.style.color = "green";
```

```css
/* Use css to select icon class (if static) */
.icon-info {
  color: pink;
}

.icon-calendar-month {
  color: purple;
}

.question {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="ic-notification ic-notification--admin-created ic-notification--info">
        <div class="ic-notification__icon" role="presentation">
          <i class="icon-info">INFO - BLUE</i></div></div>
          
  <div class="ic-notification ic-notification--admin-created ic-notification--info">
            <div class="ic-notification__icon" role="presentation">
              <i class="icon-calendar-month">CALENDAR MONTH - RED</i></div></div>

 <div class="ic-notification ic-notification--admin-created ic-notification--info">
            <div class="ic-notification__icon" role="presentation">
              <i class="question">QUESTION - GREEN</i></div></div>
```

- *(example removed from snippet): Use the :nth-child() pseudo-class ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child))*

Comment: Thanks, @Enrichdev. This is getting me closer. Each of the elements has the following css: `ic-notification__icon {
    background: var(--ic-brand-primary);
    flex: 0 0 48px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 1px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.ic-notification {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid var(--ic-brand-primary);
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Comment: The elements' positions are variable, so I am not sure the nth-child will work.

Comment: @NodindeSaillan, would Javascript help? Not sure how variable the elements are or the logic required. I have edited the answer with some simple JS code examples. If works for you, great. Else, we need more specific details.